# Nuevo en Python If

Tags: python, condiciones

Soy nuevo en Python, llevo 5 días, se me plantea el siguiente problema:
want_greet='S'

```
if want_greet in 'SNX':
    valid_options +=1
        if want_greet == 'X':
            break
```

Entre la declaración de variable y el primer if hay varias instrucciones, si corro el programa sin el segundo if funciona, al poner el segundo if want_greet... me da error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\PruebasPython\salir_bucle.py", line 10
    if want_greet == 'X':
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Alguien podría decirme que hago mal y, abusando de la ayuda, alguien sabe de algún buen tutorial de python o libro.

Gracias.

Comment: Justamente lo que te dice el mensaje de error: _IndentationError: unexpected indent_. En Python es fundamental que respetes la indentación.

Comment: Debes quitar un nivel de indentación a tus dos últimas líneas de código.

Comment: Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Tu pregunta podría terminar [cerrada](/help/closed-questions) por un par de motivos: 1. el problema se debe a un error tipográfico; 2. estás solicitando recursos externos (tutoriales, libros), haciendo que tu pregunta esté basada en opiniones. Por otra parte, redacta siempre un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta, donde se resuma brevemente el problema, y evita las salutaciones y firmas, tal como se menciona en [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](/help/behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python no existen palabras o símbolos para indicar el inicio/fin de bloque, sino que esto se hace con la indentación.

Por lo mismo, Python es estricto en cuanto a indentación se refiere y, si el interprete encuentra un cambio a la indentación del código que no está posicionado después de una instrucción que *permita* el inicio de un bloque, se va a quejar de esta situación, terminando la ejecución con un error, como estás experimentando.

Las instrucciones que *permiten* el inicio de un bloque nuevo son las que *envuelven* una funcionalidad condicional, de bucle, etc, como `if`, `while`, `def` y otras.

En este caso, si observas tu código, entre la línea 2 y la línea 3, hay un cambio a la indentación, que no sigue a una de estas instrucciones y, por tanto, probablemente pertenezcan al mismo bloque (debe tener la misma indentación) o bien falte la instrucción que da inicio al nuevo bloque. Ante esta ambigüedad, como ya he dicho, el interprete se detiene.

Suponiendo que es un mismo bloque, lo que correspondería es esto:

```
if want_greet in 'SNX':
    valid_options +=1
    if want_greet == 'X':
        break
```

Donde la línea 2 y la 3 están al mismo nivel.

Comment: indentacion ese era el problema
Gracias
Pablo